# pybind11 - Convert type B to const A* in C++ but not in python

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a polymorphic base class A and a polymorphic class B derived from A. The virtual inheritance must be and I expose both classes to python, so I will have automatic down-casting on the python side. But I explicitly do not specify that A is the parent class of B (as shown in [this](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#inheritance-and-automatic-downcasting) example, i.e. using an extra template parameter within the `py::class_`) because I don't want to expose all the base methods of A on an object of type B.

I don't want that because I essentially want to control which functions are callable on B, such that they have to be explicitly exposed again on the `py::class_` of B.

So far so good. My question is this: How can I still allow converting an object of type `B` to a `const A*`, `std::shared_ptr<const A>`, or a `const A&` for global functions defined like the `func_get_count` in my example - but without opening the door to non-const method of A. I want `func_get_count` to work for an object of type B on the python side, but not `func_inc_count`.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class A
{
public:

    virtual ~A() = default;

    int get() const
    {
        return _count;
    }

    void inc()
    {
        _count++;
    }

private:
    int _count = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

int getCount(const A* a)
{
    return a->get();
}

void incCount(A* a)
{
    a->inc();
}

std::shared_ptr<B> createB()
{
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    b->inc();
    return b;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mybind_test, m)
{
    m.doc() = "mybind is my pybind11 module to test";

    py::class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("get_count", &A::get)
        .def("inc_count", &A::inc);

    py::class_<B, std::shared_ptr<B>>(m, "B")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def("get_count", &A::get);

    m.def("func_get_count", &getCount);
    m.def("func_inc_count", &incCount);
    m.def("func_create_b", &createB);
}
```

Of course, I could just add an overload for the `getCount` function to accept parameters of type B but given a lot of these methods, is there a smarter way, less verbose, less code duplication?

```
int getCount(const B* b)
{
    return b->get();
}
```

If I add the method overload and then also the py binding with the py overload caster,

```
m.def("func_get_count", py::overload_cast<const A*>(&getCount));
m.def("func_get_count", py::overload_cast<const B*>(&getCount));
```

it seems like an overkill since the C++ side already knows how to implicitly convert a `B*` to an `const A*`...

Comment: Could be achieved using pybind type casters? I am not sure here...

Comment: I don't think so. A slight improvement on your existing code is to add a lambda function, something like: `m.def("func_get_count", [](const B* x) { return getCount(x); });`. But you'd still have to do this for every method. See https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/limitations.html: "pybind11 casts away const-ness in function arguments and return values. This is in line with the Python language, which has no concept of const values. ".